# How to delete files from media content providers on android N

Tags: android, media, android-contentprovider, android-permissions

This code worked on previous versions of android, but no longer seems to work on N.

I want to delete a media file, given the content URI of the file. I query the content provider for the path of the file. On android N, this seems to return a filename of the following form:

```
/storage/1143-1403/DCIM/Camera/20171019_185604.mp4
```

On previous versions of Android, the path would been a direct path to the SD Card. (And the real file can actually be found in the `/sdcard/DCIM/Camera` directory).

The problem: when I call `new File(path).delete()`, the delete fails. It succeeds in previous versions of Android.

Manifest permissions are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I have requested the following permissions, and they have been granted:

```
   Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    ...
    Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS,
```

There is no `Manifest.permission` flag for `WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE`.

I'm guessing `"/storage/1143-1403/DCIM/Camera"` is some kind of fused file system.

Calling `file = file.getAbsoluteFile().getCanonicalFile();` does not change the path or otherwise improve the situtation.

Comment: try using `ContentResolver`

Comment: "I query the content provider for the path of the file" -- I am guessing that you mean `MediaStore` and `_DATA`. There is no requirement that this value is useful to you. In particular, there is no requirement that you be able to read, write, or delete this file from the filesystem. "It succeeds in previous versions of Android" -- only on the devices that you tried. In particular, this behavior violates the compatibility rules for Android. You should not have direct filesystem access to arbitrary locations on removable storage.

Comment: "Manifest permissions are" -- there has never been a `WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE` or a `READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare: For media content providers (i.e.MediaStore providers), _data is documented to be a filename. For Oreo+, you can use DocomentsProvider calls to deete MediaStore providers. For <N, you have permission to delete. This is a common enough use case: manage media files. Picassa does it. as do most media apps. Hence the question: if not that way, then HOW?

Comment: "For media content providers (i.e.MediaStore providers), _data is documented to be a filename" -- citation, please, particularly where it says that you have the guaranteed ability to delete the file. "For Oreo+, you can use DocomentsProvider calls to deete MediaStore providers" -- I would not assume that to be reliable. "Hence the question: if not that way, then HOW?" -- use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, or `StorageVolume`, to get `Uri` values that are part of the Storage Access Framework and for which `DocumentsProvider` is relevant.

Comment: @CommonsWare WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE : Good to know that there never has been. The internet littered with examples of apps that do contain this permission in the manifest. I didn't have it originally. I added it to see if it makes a difference. It does not. I shall remove it. While I agree that there has never been a Manifest.permissionsWRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE  declaration, are you sure there has never been a Manifiest uses-permission named "android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"?

Comment: @psking: I can and do use content resolver to delete the file from the media store database. But that doesn't delete the file. O+ has DocumentsProvider contracts to delete the file via content resolver. But those APIs are not avaiable on N.